# R - recursive creation of folder on network drive

Tags: r

I want to create a new folder (including subfolders) on a network drive. Creating just subfolders works, but once I use the option

```
recursive=TRUE
```

I run into problems:

```
Warning message:
In dir.create(current.path, recursive = TRUE) :
   cannot create dir '\\SHARES\data', reason 'Permission denied'
```

Any solutions (apart from using a loop)?

Comment: ?Sys.chmod to see how to adjust permissions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem should be fixed in R 3.4.4.

Reference:
https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17159

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!